# Visual Studio Code For Mac

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have enrolled new team which are using Visual Studio, but I have a MAC computer. I have a chance to get Windows computer also, but I am curious about something. Can I use Visual Studio Code instead of Win Visual Studio? Has it all properties of Win version?

Comment: boot camp + windows?

Comment: I think, this is not useful for longtime usage

Comment: Whether it's suitable for use depends on what your team will be developing. Visual Studio Code for Mac and Windows is the same, but neither has all the features of Visual Studio. Figure out what it is you'll be doing, then see if Visual Studio Code has the same capabilities. No one on SO can give you a definitive setup without knowing a whole lot more.

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not. `Visual Studio Code` for mac is mostly an editor, not a full fledged IDE as `Visual Studio` for Windows is. [Check out the FAQ](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/faq).

Comment: Do you advise me to use VS for WIN for totally programming right?

Comment: Well, it depends on what you want to program on: C#, Java, Visual Basic.NET, Python, Ruby,,,

Answer (score 0):

You can use Visual Studio Code on Windows, but is only a editor and not a IDE like Visual Studio, then maybe the best is if you need have windows install Visual Studio and also install ReSharper or another tools.

If you love Mac/linux and don't feel very comfortable with Windows, you can work with Visual Code with any problem or use [Rider project](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/?fromMenu)

is a new IDE for C# for run net core app.